# Using an enum in generic function

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, generics, swift3

I want to create a generic function with an enum as generic parameters. 
I have the following generic function:

```
func buildProvider<T>(service: T) -> RxMoyaProvider<T> {

    let endpointClosure = { (target: T) -> Endpoint<T> in
        let url = target.baseURL.appendingPathComponent(target.path).absoluteString
        let endpoint = Endpoint<T>(URL: url, sampleResponseClosure: {.networkResponse(200, target.sampleData)}, method: target.method, parameters: target.parameters)
        return endpoint
    }

    return RxMoyaProvider<T>(endpointClosure: endpointClosure)
}
```

I call it like this:

```
self.userProvider = buildProvider(service: UserService)
```

Below you see the declaration of userProvider:

var userProvider: RxMoyaProvider?

And below you see an example of UserService:

```
import Foundation
import Moya

enum UserService {
    case login(qrKey: String, language: String, fcmToken: String)
}

extension UserService: TargetType {

    var baseURL: URL {
        let appConfig = AppConfig()
        let hostname = try! appConfig.hostname()

        return URL(string: hostname)!
    }
    var path: String {
        switch self {
        case .login(_,_,_):
            return "/v1/login"
        }
    }
    var method: Moya.Method {
        switch self {
        case .login(_,_,_):
            return .post
        }
    }
    var parameters: [String: Any]? {
        switch self {
        case .login(let qrKey, let language, let fcmToken):
            let params = ["qr-key": qrKey, "language": language, "os": "ios", "fcm-token": fcmToken]
            return params
        }
    }
    var sampleData: Data {
        switch self {
        case .login(_, _, _):
            return "".data(using: .utf8)!
        }
    }
    var task: Task {
        return .request
    }
}
```

And I get the following error:

```
 Cannot convert value of type 'UserService.Type' to expected argument type 'UserService'
```

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks !

Comment: on which exact string you get this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience with Moya and can not know for sure how it works and what you're trying to achieve, but it seems like you're trying to pass type into function. If so you must do something like:

```
func buildProvider<T>(service: T.Type) -> RxMoyaProvider<T> {

    ...

    return RxMoyaProvider<T>(endpointClosure: endpointClosure)
}
```

and call it with `.self`:

```
self.userProvider = buildProvider(service: UserService.self)
```

but it's not your only problem. How do you know without context that type `<T>` would have `baseURL` property:

```
let endpointClosure = { (target: T) -> Endpoint<T> in
    let url = target.baseURL.appendingPathComponent(target.path).absoluteString
```

?

Seems like you've messed up with overall architecture, and I would strongly advice to reconsider it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, got it working. TargetType is a class inside Moya which always has a property of baseURL. So i'm going to accept this answer !

Comment: well, my bad with TargetType! anyway glad to help :)